# A die is rolled three times. Find the chance that: Two of the numbers are the same and the third is different?

Tags: probability

Why is it not:

1*(1/6)*(5/6)

My rationale is that the chance of rolling the first number can be any number therefore it's 6/6.  The chance of rolling the same number as the first then would be 1/6 and lastly in order for the third number to be different the chance of that is 5/6.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dice are red, white and blue then you have the probability the red and white dice are the same and the blue is different.  But there are other cases:

- the blue and red dice are the same and the white is different
- the white and blue dice are the same and the red is different

so the question may expect an answer three times yours

Comment: Are you sure? the third must be different, which are the other cases?

Comment: @gimusi It depends on what the question means by "the third".  I suspect it simply means that two are the same and one different.  I have edited my answer showing this using colours

Comment: Yes indeed at first I was giving the answer by the not ordered case but reading again the OP I supposed that we were dealing with an ordered case.

Comment: OP is asking of one die. Not several dies with several colors

Comment: @Joe - they are equivalent questions.  But the key point is that when the question says *the third* it does not just mean the final throw or the blue die, just the one that does not match the other two

Answer (score 1):

Note that if we **take into account the order** the answer is correct, indeed, in another way, the cases we are looking for are 30 that is 11,22,33,44,55,66 for the first two dice and for each we have 5 different possibilities for the third die thus

$$p=\frac{30}{6^3}=\frac5{36}$$

If the **order doesn't count** we should multiply the result by 3 (indeed 116,161,611 are equivalent) thus we have

$$p=3\frac{30}{6^3}=3\frac5{36}=\frac5{12}$$

Or in another way we can calculate the probability that all dice are different or equals and take the complement that is

- probability that all different $\frac{6\cdot 5 \cdot 4}{6^3}=\frac{5}{9}$
- probability that all are equal $\frac{6}{6^3}=\frac{1}{36}$

$$p=1-\frac{5}{9}-\frac{1}{36}=\frac{36-20-1}{36}=\frac{15}{36}=\frac{5}{12}$$

Comment: Because it's the probability that the first two numbers rolled are equal (and the third isn't), and so is one-third of the correct answer.

Comment: Looking at the solution here the supposed correct answer is:

1- ((1/6 * 1/6) +(5/6 * 4/6))

 I'm very confused as to why the compliment rule was even needed in this case

Comment: @Spiers this result is correct if we have an order otherwise we have other cases, so you are not completely wrong, it is a matter of interpretation of the question

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown ok now is clear, as the problem is stated one could assume that there is an order so we can distinguish the first and second dice from the third. Of course if we don't have that order the aswer is three times the probability for the ordered.

Comment: @Spiers:  $1- \left(\left(\frac16 \times \frac16\right) +\left(\frac56 \times \frac46\right)\right) = \frac{15}{36}$  which is also $3 \times \left(1 \times \frac16 \times \frac56\right)$

Comment: @gimusi Ahh I see what you mean.

Comment: @Henry I see so there are basically three different orders that this probability can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for "the first two to be equal and the third different" or "exactly two out the three are equal" ?

If it's the later, i think it's easier first to compute the probability of the complement : "either the three are different or the three are equal". That would be $\frac{6\times5\times4}{6^3}+\frac{6\times1\times1}{6^3}-0=\frac{7}{12}$.

Therefore, the probability that "exactly two out of three are equal" is $1-\frac{7}{12}=\frac{5}{12}$.